# Mac prevent managed account from opening terminal

Tags: macos

I was wondering if it was possible to stop a managed account on Mac OS X 10.7 from opening a terminal window, without using parental controls.

Are there any programs that are on the market that would instantly kill terminal if it were open (as well as other programs in the utilities folder)

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Why not use Parental Controls? It has a feature that's designed for this.

Comment: I'm a network administrator, so its an arduous task to set every single mac (more than 1000) up with parental controls. We haven't distributed them yet, so i wanted it to work when we flashed the image, and let the Users set up their own account

Comment: Did you have a chance to try changing permissions as described in my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to change permissions:

1. Open Applications>Utilties in Finder
2. Select Terminal and press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>.
3. Click the lock at the bottom of the Get Info window.
4. In Sharing & Permissions set *everyone* to *No Access* and give the users who are allowed to open Terminal *Read only* privilege:

[image]

You may see a cosmetic side effect: Terminal gets a new icon:

[image]

This is temporary until next reboot (or until you relaunch the Finder in Apple menu>Force Quit...).

Answer (score 0):

Will it be easier to put an exit in the profile before imaging?

`cd /Users/Username-of-user`
`touch .bash_profile ; chmod 644 .bash_profile ; echo exit >> .bash_profile`